# create new record using many to many relation in php for yiiframework

Tags: php, yii

Hi I am quite new to php 
Here i have two models as users and roles, they have many to relation through third model as
users_roles.

following are my models as
Users.php

```
public function relations()
    {       
        return array(
            'userRoles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRoles', 'id_users'),
        );
    }
```

Roles.php

```
public function relations()
    {       
        return array(           
            'userRoles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'UserRoles', 'id_roles'),
        );
    }
```

UsersRoles.php

```
public function relations()
    {           
        return array(
            'idUsers' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'id_users'),
            'idRoles' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Roles', 'id_roles'),
        );
    }
```

Now when i creating users I added roles using checkboxes as

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'roles'); ?>       
        <?php 

        //print_r($userRoles);
        //die;

        echo CHtml::activeCheckboxList(
                $userRoles, 'id_roles',
                CHtml::listData(Roles::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),
                array('template'=>'{input} {label}',)
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'roles'); ?>
```

now how can i save those checkbox values in my users_roles tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your relations for Users and Roles have a typo, they both refer to model UserRoles when it should be UsersRoles.

Now to your question.  I would create a function in the UsersRoles model named something like refreshRoles($user, $roles).  Where $user is the user id you are selecting roles for, and $roles is an array of roles that should be set.  The function would retrieve the list of Roles by id_users, and compare it to $roles, deleting roles that are missing from $roles, and adding roles that are missing from the UsersRoles table.

That would look something like this:

```
function refreshRoles($user, $roles) {
   $userRoles = $this->findAllByAttribute(array('id_users' => $user));
   foreach ($userRoles as $userRole) {
      if (!in_array($userRole->id_roles, $roles)) {
         $userRole->delete();
      }
      else {
         $key = array_search($userRole->id_roles, $roles));
         unset($roles[$key]);
   }
   foreach ($roles as $role) {
      $model = new UsersRoles();
      $model->id_users = $user;
      $model->id_roles = $role;
      $model->save(false);
   }
}
```

Call this function from your controller just after you save your user model (if you are indeed saving the user).  Note, this is untested, but will give you a direction to head.

Comment: how can I call this function in my controller because when i select multiple checkboxes it gives me array of selected i tried this `UserRoles::model()->refreshRoles($model->id,$id_roles);`

Comment: What happened when you did this?